# Nautilus manages/show my icons on the desktop, but Dolphin is called when a folder is opened

Tags: gnome3, nautilus

Nautilus (nautilus-desktop) manages/shows my icons on the desktop, but whenever I click on a folder found on the desktop, it is Dolphin that is being opened.  This is on Ubuntu 18.04, Gnome 3.28.2.

I cannot figure out how to configure Nautilus to open another Nautilus instance when clicking on a folder found on the desktop.  Can someone tell me how?

I search through `~/.local` and `~/.config` for "dolphin" (ignoring case) but no matches. Found nothing in the preferences regarding this issue.  `strace nautilus-desktop` did not help either.

Comment: Is it only on the desktop? Try `xdg-open folder` and see what program pops up. `folder` being a random folder you have access to. It might be the case that `Dolphin` is set up as your default file manger.

Comment: `xdg-open folder` starts Nautilus.  The mystery persists.  Thank you @rudib for helping.

Comment: I don't have a nautilus Desktop at my disposal right now, but what happens if you `rightclick->open with`? Maybe you have `plasma-systemsettings` installed as well? If that's the case, check your defaullt applications there too. Also, make sure, that there actually are folders, and not `.desktop` entries with a folder icon (by running `ls ~/Desktop` and `ls -l ~/Desktop | grep '^d'`).